# Consulta MySQL para elegir horarios disponibles en tabla

Tags: mysql

Mi duda es como formular una consulta para seleccionar horarios disponibles en una tabla, el planteamiento es el siguiente:

Tengo dos tablas: horarios y citas

```
Horarios
id|hora
1|08:0
2|09:00
3|10:00
4|11:00
5|12:00

citas
id|nombre|hora
1|juan|09:00
2|jose|10:00
3|maria|12:00
```

en la consulta necesito que me arroje de la tabla horarios el resultado los horarios disponibles: 08:00 y 11:00

Comment: Intentaste algo?

Comment: hacer un LEFT JOIN, pero me arroja error

Comment: agrega lo que intentaste a la pregunta, asi podemos ayudarte diciendote que es lo que esta mal...

Comment: como ligas la tabla de citas con horarios?

Comment: a simple vista, viendo lo que publicaste, como mencionan en los comentario debes hacer un LEFT JOIN y luego filtrar aquellos que no tengan relación, algo así  `SELECT Horarios.hora FROM Horarios LEFT JOIN citas ON Horarios.hora = citas.hora WHERE ISNULL(citas.id)`

Comment: Pon lo q has intentado para poderte ayudar